# How to find arabic character all occurrences with its dialect?

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to find the occurence of arabic character with its harakat in string such as "رَّ" in "بِسْمِ ٱللَّهِ ٱلرَّحْمَٰنِ ٱلرَّحِيمِ".

Arabic characters can take harakat for example "ر" is the original arabic character but can have harakat so it can look something like this "رَّ"> I am using Python 3 to find the character occurence with a specific harakat but could not do that. I have tried for loop and tried converting the string to unicode but could not do that.

```py
str = "مرة رجل حكيم قال بِسْمِ ٱللَّهِ ٱلرَّحْمَٰنِ ٱلرَّحِيمِ"
i=0
for s in str:
    if s == "رَّ":
        i = i + 1
print(i)
```

Expected output is 2 but 0 is what I get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`len("رَّ")` returns `3`, which means the glyph is represented by three characters.  Your loop checks a single character at a time and so never finds a match.

You need to be looking for substrings, which is exactly what `.count()` is for.

```
i = str.count('رَّ')
```

Comment: It works thanx, but now I got another problem is that when counting the same letter without any dialect I get duplicate as it will count the letters that have dialect. How can I count the letters that have no dialect?

Comment: One way would be: after counting 'رَّ', use `str = str.replace('رَّ','')` to remove those instances, then do your search for 'ر'.  To generalize, it is important to check the basic character last.